# C# Should I place the Sql/OleDb transaction.Commit() outside of a for loop?

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope

I have the following basic oledb loop:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Con))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        for loop 
        {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        cmd.CommandText = "row by row insert"
        cmd.Some parameters, then ExecuteNonQuery
        transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not certain if I should be placing the `Commit` within the loop after the command execution. Should I place it after all is said and done? Outlining the `using` would be a `try catch` containing a rollback in the `catch`. So I'm guessing if I want to be able to rollback all of my changes, I will want the loop to run completely, and then commit it?

I also just learned about `TransactionScope`s which outline the SQL context in a using, so I'd like to know how it applies to that as well.

Comment: Depends on your requirements. Should all `INSERT` commands be reset if one fails?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's right. So if it's within the loop, the most the catch will roll back would be the last row added? Also, I'm trying to use the TransactionScope, I added the reference and such, I assume this will work with any database agnostic of the platform? Cause I don't see anywhere to define it. @JanesAbouChleih

Comment: Exactly, your code now, would only reset the transaction for the last `INSERT`. If you put it outside the loop (with `conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);` of course) it will reset all `INSERT` commands handled in this transaction/for loop. 
But right now, there's still some exception handling missing where you handle `transaction.Rollback()`. €: As @Mike Nakis already stated it also has a huge impact on the performance of your db, since all transactions are logged. Therefore less transactions = faster performance. I didn't understand the `TransactionScope` question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot move the `Commit()` call outside the loop when the `BeginTransaction()` call is inside the loop.  Either both will stay in the loop, or both will go outside the loop.

So, your question should be: "should I perform one transaction per iteration of my loop, or should I start a transaction, do my loop, and then commit the transaction?"

Well, the only reason for doing one transaction per iteration would be the very unlikely scenario where you would want all non-failing insertions to be committed even if some of them fail.  (In which case you would also need to do some exception handling.)

If you do not have such a requirement, and if you would not mind an order-of-magnitude performance improvement, then you better start a transaction, do your loop, then close your transaction.